# Javascript Inserting Dynamic Row in Main Page

Tags: javascript, dynamic, rows

I have two pages: one is the Main and one is the Popup that I grab data and submit back into the main page. It seems to work OK in Chrome and in FF, but doesnt in IE. I get an error message "No Such Interface Supported". This seems to happen to everyone I ask to test on IE.

I think it has something to do with the way I'm appending dynamic rows to main page. I am just not sure how I should go about to do it right.

Here is the code I use:

```
function addRowForPC(pcT,pcP)  {
    try {
        var tableID="Equipment"; 
        var table = window.opener.document.getElementById(tableID);              
        var rowCount = table.rows.length - 0;             
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);    

        insertFld( "delEquip", "image"   , table, rowCount, row, 0 ) //Image
        insertFld( pcT       , "text"    , table, rowCount, row, 1 ) //Text
        insertFld( pcP       , "textSpan", table, rowCount, row, 2 ) //Text
}

    catch(err) { 
        alert(err.message);
        return "Fail";
    }
}

//This calls: to create the rows:
function insertFld(fldName,fldType,table,rowCount,row,insCell)   {
    try {   
        var cellName = "cell" + (insCell+1);
        cellName = row.insertCell(insCell);

        switch (fldType) {
            case "image":
                        var image = document.createElement('img');
                        image.src="Images/delete.jpg";
                        image.alt ="Remove";
                        image.name=fldName +rowCount;
                        image.setAttribute('width','10');
                        image.setAttribute('height','10');
                        image.onclick= function(){deleteRow(this)}; 
                        cellName.appendChild(image); 
                        break;
            case "text":
                        cellName.innerHTML = fldName;
                        break;
            case "textSpan":
                        cellName.colSpan="2";
                        cellName.innerHTML = fldName;
                        break;
        }
    }

    catch(err) {    
        alert (err.message);
    }
}
```

Any help/guidance would be great.  I'm new to JavaScript/HTML so I don't really even know where would start with jQuery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE?  If its 9 then open up the developer tools, go to the Javascript tab and turn on debugging then run the code.  It may give you some useful details.  If not then start by commenting most of the code out and run it, if it works then comment some back in and try again until you find the locaton that's causing the error.

I would also try moving some of the code to the opener window, and then calling the function on it, like:

```
addRowForPC(pcT,pcP) {
    opener.addRowForPC(pcT,pcP);
}
```

In fact taking a second look at your code, I'm thinking its the document.createElement() call that's the problem, if its running in the context of the popup window and then the results are being added to the opener.  You might be able to do opener.document.createElement() to ensure the element is associated with the opener document and not the popup.